# Приоритет операции инкрементирования

Tags: java, операторы, инкремент

Пытаюсь разобраться в приоритетах операций по следующему примеру:

```
int a = 2; int b = 3; int c = 9;

a += --a + a * ++a;
c += --b != 3 > ++c;    
b = ++c + --a == 3 * ++b != ++c + --b <= ++b;
```

Выполнил в Eclipse `a += --a + a * ++a;` — выдало значение переменной `a` равное 5, но когда я считаю самостоятельно, то получаю иное значение этой переменной.

Пожалуйста, объясните мне каждый шаг исполнения приведенных мной кодов.

Comment: Так какие значения получились после вычисления выражений, и какие значения должны быть по вашему мнению?!

Comment: не минус 5, а просто 5. в принципе все логично. Хотя такие конструкции - изуверство

Comment: Там не минус,а просто тире. Я считал таким образом (это в примере :  a+=--a + a* ++a;, далее просто уже не имело смысла лезть из-за непонимания) : сначала инкремент ++,далее декремент -- (если они перед переменной стоят,как я помню они имеют самый высший приоритет из всех операторов в Java,потому я начал вычислять сначала их),умножение и прибавление, в итоге результат 8.

Comment: Это на одном образовательном сайте,тест такой.

Comment: Спасибо Вам,что отозвались.

Comment: Скобки ставьте и не парьтесь с приоритетом.

Answer (score 2):

Вот аналогичный деассемблированный С# код:

```
            int a = 2;
01812DC5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],2     ; a = 2

            a += --a + a * ++a;
01812DCC  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]   ; eax = a(2)
01812DCF  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax   ; buf1 = eax(2)
01812DD2  dec         dword ptr [ebp-40h]       ; a = a(2) - 1
01812DD5  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]   ; eax = a(1)
01812DD8  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax   ; buf2 = eax(1)
01812DDB  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]   ; eax = a(1)
01812DDE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax   ; buf3 = eax(1)
01812DE1  inc         dword ptr [ebp-40h]       ; a = a(1) + 1
01812DE4  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h]   ; eax = buf1(2)
01812DE7  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]   ; eax = eax(2) + buf2(1)
01812DEA  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]   ; edx = a(2)
01812DED  imul        edx,dword ptr [ebp-50h]   ; edx = edx(2) * buf3(1)
01812DF1  add         eax,edx                   ; eax = eax(3) + edx(2)
01812DF3  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax   ; a = eax(5)
```

Т.е. состояние переменной `a` изменялось следующим образом:

```
a += --a + a * ++a; // a = ?
2 += --a + a * ++a; // a = 2
2 += 1 + a * ++a;   // a = 1
2 += 1 + 1 * ++a;   // a = 1
2 += 1 + 1 * 2;     // a = 2
2 += 1 + 2;         // a = 2
2 += 3;             // a = 2
5;                  // a = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае, а вы не указали компилятор, флаги компиляции и вообще язык - правильный ответ один: "неопределённое поведение".

Сами инкременты/декременты обычно вычисляются в первую очередь (хотя только обычно,, конкретный стандарт конкретного языка может иметь другое мнение), а вот в каком порядке между собой - уже вопрос.

Например, выражение

```
--a + a * ++a
```

Может быть выполнено в порядке: --a, ++a, *, +. Может быть ++a, *, +, --a, может быть ++a, --a, *, +. Результаты, разумеется, будут разные. Но все одновременно верные. Какой именно вариант будет использован - зависит от:

- стандарта используемого языка, может там явно указан порядок вычисления операндов
- конкретного компилятора
- конкретной версии компилятора
- и даже конкретных флагов компиляции
- хорошо если не от фазы луны и температуры на Марсе, т.е. хотя бы на конкретном компиляторе воспроизводится от сборки к сборке

Называется неопределённым поведением. За такой код надо очень больно бить по рукам, но нередкий вопрос на всяких собеседованиях.